# onclick with javascript and animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, animate.css

I don't get it why this won't work.

I did an animation on my div class header (fadeInDownBig);
What I want is when I click on a link (a href) is that my header does fadeOutUpBig.

```js
<script>
               $(function(){
     $("a").click(function(){
      $("#header1").addClass('animated fadeOutUpBig');
     }); 
    });
                        </script>
```

```css
.header{
 margin-left:10px;
 height:350px;
 Background:url(../img/background_header2.jpg);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="header animated fadeInDownBig" id="header1" >
      <div class="menu">
       <a class="wow animated fadeIn hvr-grow-shadow transition" data-wow-delay="0.5s" href="../index.html" >Home </a>
```

What am I doing wrong ? 
(does not include animate.css)

Comment: You are redirecting user, where do you expect animation ?

Comment: The problem is, you have the classes added in the html. Remove the "animate" and the "fadeInDownBig" from the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment above mentioned clicking on an anchor will redirect you before the animations can take place. With javascript you can make it not do its default action at all on click by adding `return false` or `preventDefault` at the end.

I've made an [**Example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/rxGzbe) with the above code.

Code:

```
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {

    $("#header").addClass('animated fadeOutUpBig');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: THANK YOU ! I did some changes in it to make it work. Because I had already a script running before that faded out the header just added it before ! Many thanks ^^